# Calculate max and min score in PHP?

Tags: php, max, min

I am creating a hobby soccer stats site. Here are some scores:

Player1 - Player2

- 5:1
- 5:2
- 0:4
- 0:1

For player1 I am trying to find the best and worst score with php. I tried a mysql_fetch_array with

```
$player1max = $row['MAX(player1)'];
```

however I get the score 5:2. However the correct score would be 5:1 as in this case player1 received only one goal.

The same happens with

```
$player1min = $row['MIN(player1)'];
```

I get 0:1, but I should get 0:4 (because getting 4 goals is worse then 1).

Comment: Please include your query in the question.

Comment: `MAX(column)` will give you, on a string, the last one if they are ordered alphabetically. If you want to calculate the max of a goal difference, store the goals separately as integers and do `MAX(goals_scored - goals_conceded)`.

Comment: You need to separate the two values, and calculate the difference - why don't you refactor your database to use two columns PLAYER1_FOR and PLAYER1_AGAINST

Comment: You should have one column for goals for, and another column for goals against.  Then you can do a query to order by goals_for DESC, goals_against ASC LIMIT 1 to get the best player.  Then do a query to order by goals_against DESC, goals_for ASC LIMIT 1 to get the worst player.

Comment: @Michael - no, I think the best/worst is on goal _difference_, not just the number of goals against.

Comment: @halfer - Ah, so 6:3 would be worse than 5:1 when trying to pick the best score?  Separating in two fields would still make it easier to get the best and worst player straight from the query though.  Just voted up your comment, think you should put that in an answer.

Comment: @Michael: yes, 5:1 is better than 6:3, indeed. Would put in an answer, but Highmastdon beat me to it. Vote him up instead `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the counter-goals extract from the make-goals and the result is either best or worst.

Example:

- 5:1 becomes 4 (5-1)
- 5:2 becomes 3 (5-2)
- 0:4 becomes -4 (0-4)
- 0:1 becomes -1 (0-1)

That way:
Worst score = -4 (0:4) 
Best score = 4 (5:1)